# Assign unique value out of multiple columns (allowed values)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling to assign a unique value to a column / index out of multiple allowed values (other columns). for example:
[image: see this small table]

So I would assign either vertex 4 or 2 to edge 0, vertex 1 or 2 to edge 1, etc. But, every edge should have an unique vertex assigned to them!

So if I take edge0 = vertex4, edge1 = vertex1, edge2 = vertex3, ... then edge3 can only choose between vertex 1 or 4, which is already taken by one of the other edges.

In this case edge0 = vertex2, edge1 = vertex1, edge2 = vertex3 and edge3 = vertex4, would work!

In the end there will still be combinations that will leave an "edge" without a unique vertex, but then this edge should just get a NaN value or so.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Cheer,
Glenn

Comment: does every vertex have a maximum number of edges adjacent to and if so what is this number? If it is larger than 2 there is no general solution.

Comment: every edge always has two vertices. but a vertex can have more edges, thats what I mean by setting those edges to NaN then

Comment: But only when we are sure that no other combination would work (like in my example, there should not be NaNs)

Comment: would it be possible to assign a tuple to each edge? This way you could have a unique two number tuple for every edge without exception. It would add the advantage, that you could implement directed edges if necessary as well.

Comment: If you are just following a closed loop line, this has a mathematical solution. If you are looking at a general mesh, there is no non-ambiguous solution, but there will always be a multitude of solutions. In your example you have a triangle with a dangling tail, and you can traverse the triangle clockwise or counterclockwise, both would work.  In more complex meshes where many paths are possible, it'd be better to just take the earliest combination you can find which has `N` unique vertices assigned to edges, corresponding to `N` actually unique vertices in your drawing..

Comment: @Chris, no because that's basically the definition of an edge and here I more or less want to cluster edges with on of their vertices.

Comment: @Uvar, I'm indeed only interested in a possible solution (not all of them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a more elegant solution to this, but this will at least do the trick..

```
u1 = set(df["Vertex1"])
u2 = set(df["Vertex2"])
sd = u1.symmetric_difference(u2)
ist = u1.intersection(u2)
edge = {}
for i, v in enumerate(df.index):
    vert1 = df["Vertex1"].iloc[i]
    vert2 = df["Vertex2"].iloc[i]
    if vert1 in sd:
        edge[v] = vert1
        sd.discard(vert1)
    elif vert2 in sd:
        edge[v] = vert2
        sd.discard(vert2)
    elif vert1 in ist:
        edge[v] = vert1
        ist.discard(vert1)
    elif vert2 in ist:
        edge[v] = vert2
        ist.discard(vert2)
    else:
        edge[v] = math.nan

print(edge)
#{0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 4}
```

Comment: might have some typos, like square brackets on function calls...hold on